# Comment .XML file content using ruby code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra

Can anyone tell me how I can comment the following line in my .XML file using Ruby?

I hope this can be done by using "nokogiri".

```
<message group="1" sub_group="1" type="none" destination="mydata" remark="mylist" userOnly="true "/>
```

output should be:

```
<!-- <message group="1" sub_group="1" type="none" destination="mydata" remark="mylist" userOnly="true "/> -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search your document with the `search` method, add a comment with `Comment.new` and then remove the original line with the `remove` method.

```
Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(doc, node.to_s)
```

[Class: Nokogiri::XML::Comment](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Comment)

**Edit:**
I implemented an example, but used `replace` instead of `remove`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open('./config.xml')
x = Nokogiri::XML(f);
x.search('message').each do |el|
    puts(el.to_s)
    c = Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(x, el.to_s);
    el.replace(c);
end

File.write('./config.xml', x.to_xml);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. can u just explain this further. suppose  my file name is config.xml which has the above block and I need to comment that line.

Comment: Thanks David for the support. I will check this and confirm!